# Invalid magic number and need to load kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, find

I'm **new** to try Ubuntu on my broken laptop to backup some files before reinstall W10. I downloaded *Ubuntu 22.04 LTS* through official website and used Rufus to create a bootable USB with that ISO thing that I named the volume label *"RESCUE"*. I plugged the bootable USB in and selected it, then this is `GNU GRUB VERSION 2.06` I enter *Ubuntu (safe graphic)*. But this happen;

```
error: Invalid magic number.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

I discovered that there is grub command. I looked up and I tried to type this.

```
ls (hd0) (hd0.msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos6) (hd2) (hd2,msdos1)
```

I view every one by using `ls` command. `(hd0.msdos1)` which is the RESCUE. `(hd0)` said no specific or something. According of what I found from internet so far, they mentioned *vmlinux generic* or something but I tried to use `find` command and it said invalid command. `search` does not work either because it says *unspecified file*. I find every folder as possible as I can but I could not find *vmlinux generic*

How should I command? What should I do?

Comment: Did you rename the USB volume to "RESCUE"? Because renaming it could cause this. Can you reflash and retry to boot from the USB?

Comment: No, I did not rename it after Rufus. I name the volume on the Rufus! I'll retry it for now since it's night right now.

Comment: The USB that you are using has not enough space for the installation. Try with a bigger one.